# Probability space of an experiment that returns a random rational number between 0 and 1

Tags: probability

I just started learning about probability and the following question came up. Lets say we have an experiment that will return a random rational number between 0 and 1, each number being equally likely. How would one describe this experiment with a probabilty space? One cant assign every number an equal positive probability. One cant assign every number probability zero since than the probability of the countable sum of all the rationals would be zero.

Is the problem that the experiment doesnt make sense so there is no sensible probability space to describe it? Is there some sensible probability space to describe this experiment, if so what is it?

Comment: The probability space is $[0,1]$, and the measure is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @GNU Supporter Lebesgue measure is on reals, not rationals

Comment: I think the confusion arises from trying to picture this "experiment".  How is this number being returned?  As a fraction?  But the probability that either the numerator or the denominator can be written using all the protons in the universe is $0$.   In practice I expect you mean that it returns a bunch of digits in a decimal expansion, but then it is indistinguishable from a uniform random process on the reals, practically speaking.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot have a uniform distribution over a countably infinite probability space, as you need to be able to add up these probabilities to get $1$ so the constant probability of each event can be neither zero (adding up to $0$) nor positive (adding up to $\infty$).